# Virtual Host doesn't work with URI in Apache 2... laravel 4.2 and laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-4, apache2, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

I am working with Laravel 5

I have created a virtual host **demo.com** which is pointed to the public folder of laravel .It runs fine in browser and shows me the index.php file. But when I try **demo.com/home** I get an 404 error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at demo.com Port 80
```

The routes.php looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

it runs fine when I use the Laravel development server, by doing php artisen serve and then type in browser **localhost:8000/home** which takes me to the default auth login page.

The config file in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/demo.com.conf** looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo.com
    ServerAlias demo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/demo/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/demoError.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/demoAccess.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and the **/etc/hosts** looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   demo.com
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: your `Homecontroller` in the controller root directory or under other sub directory into controller directory?

Comment: I apologize I did not get your question.

Comment: the path of the home controller  in the demo project folder is as follows.
demo/app/httpd/controllers/HomeController.php

Comment: you should put your controller directory under app directory.

Comment: Try `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: You din't say whether you have apache mod_rewrite enabled. If you haven't, you will need this.

Comment: I guess it is a problem with not enabling your apache mod_rewrite module  as you say it is working with laravel development server.